# update pdf automatically using texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using texstudio on mac os x. Each time I change some sentences in my .tex file and I need to see the results, I have to close the previous .pdf (if it is already opened) and regenerate the .pdf. Is it possible to update the pdf automatically without doing each time close open.thanks.

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: @PaulGessler I use Acrobat professional reader

Comment: I don't use texstudio, so I can't test this or help much further, but [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/16/) may help. The problem is that Adobe software locks the PDF file, so nothing can open it for writing while it's open in any Adobe software. The workaround described in the link (and others for other IDEs I've seen) uses dynamic data exchange (DDE) commands for interprocess communication. The idea is to have the IDE/editor tell Adobe to close the file, then run pdf(La)TeX/whatever else, and then signal Adobe to re-open the file.

Comment: The alternative, of course, is to switch PDF viewers to one which _doesn't_ lock the file.

Comment: @PaulGessler thanks! how can I change the viewer on latex studio. May be I can use preview on mac os.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

I'd recommend you to use the **internal PDF viewer** because it allows more accurate synchronization between PDF and source. Also, it does not have the closing issue. Check that you have the following settings
[image: internal PDF Viewer configuration]

If you have a good reason to stay with **Adobe Acrobat**, here is a description how to setup DDE to automatically close the PDF before compilation:
https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/650/

Answer (score 2):

If it works the same as on Windows, it's `Options -> Configure TeX Studio -> Build -> PDF Viewer`, and also `... -> \Build -> Default Viewer`. For both, you have the choice between `Internal PDF Viewer (Embedded)`,  `Internal PDF Viewer (Windowed)` and `External PDF Viewer`.

Comment: I changed the three values. But It did not works.

Comment: I modified slightly my answer; there's also a `Default Viewer`item to check. Did you save the new settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have a small script in python which does the following:

```
import time
import os
while (True):
        os.system("xelatex yourOptionsHere youfile.tex")
        time.sleep(5)
```

But I can tell you, doing so sucks the processor !!